# Transfer a national domain to foreign registrar?

Tags: domain-transfer

Can you transfer a national domain (like .pl) to a foreign registrar, one that does not actually offer buying that type of domain?

Answer (score 1):

Not usually, no. There has to be an infrastructure in place to support it.

Try visiting the registrar's contact page and contact them directly about it.